# Cached Network Image onLoaded function?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to get an indication as to when the Cached Network Image has completed loading the image? There is a placeholder, so there must be a way to get a indicator as to when it stops using the placeholder without using a placeholder yes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *progressIndicatorBuilder* I don't know if this is the best way but it can help you

```
progressIndicatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, String url, DownloadProgress downloadProgress) {
  //do something with value when value == 1
  double? value = downloadProgress.progress; //between 0 and 1
  return Container();
},
```